# Setting emptyText on a parsys from Sightly (AEM6)

Tags: aem, sightly

In Sightly/AEM6, when including a parsys component, how can I set the text that says 'Drag Components Here' (cq:emptyText) to use a localised string? I have several parsys components as children of a custom component and need different text for each (e.g. Drag image components here, drag link components here).

Comment: I also faced a similar issue and after finding no suitable answers anywhere, decided to do my own solution and wrote a detailed blog entry explaining it: https://scribcopia.wordpress.com/2017/08/13/customizing-text-within-parsys-touch-ui/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems to be hard coded to use a specific I18n string, in /libs/cq/gui/components/authoring/clientlibs/editor/js/model/Inspectable.js

However, I was able to override the parsys control and change the CSS classes of the newpar from `new section` to `cq-placeholder section` and then include `data-emptytext="Custom text"` on the same html element.

Comment: Would you be able to post some code details? I'm trying to do the same thing, and I haven't found a way to get data attributes on the "new" div.

Answer (score 1):

in CQ5.6 we can do the following, maybe it works with AEM 6:

- inherit your component from /libs/foundation/components/parsys
- add a node which name is 'new' under your component node, which sling:resourceType is foundation/components/parsys/new or just copy the /libs/foundation/components/parsys/new
- add cq:emptyText property to this node, which is the text appear in the box.

Comment: the new Sightly parsys is at /libs/wcm/foundation/components/parsys, it has a child component at /libs/wcm/foundation/components/parsys/newpar. Unfortunately inheriting this componenent and setting cq:emptyText does not work, I guess it's stored somewhere else now

Comment: you'll need to inherit both, the parsys and the newpar and in the parsys, you need to reference your newpar.

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content" data-sly-list="${properties.titles}"> 
    <div data-sly-test.resourcePath1="${'{0}{1}' @ format=['tab',itemList.index]}" class="${itemList.index != 0 && wcmmode.isPreview ? 'tab-pane fade' : 'tab-pane fade in active'}" id="${item}">

        <div data-sly-resource="${ resourcePath1 @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys/newpar'}" class="cq-placeholder section" data-emptytext="${item}'s content"></div>

</div>
```